# Json_encode or remove last comma?

Tags: php, json

I figured out how to get my desired result (almost).  My code adds a comma at the end before the last ] so it wont quite work.  I know I can use Json_encode to build my array from my external json but I'm stumped.  I either need to remove the last comma or use json_encode (which i'm lost on) any better ideas?

Code:

Original JSON

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": 1383609600,
        "localTimestamp": 1383609600,
        "issueTimestamp": 1383609600,
        "fadedRating": 4,
        "solidRating": 0,
        "swell": {
            "minBreakingHeight": 4,
            "absMinBreakingHeight": 3.836,
            "maxBreakingHeight": 6,
            "absMaxBreakingHeight": 5.992,
            "unit": "ft",
            "components": {
                "combined": {
                    "height": 7,
                    "period": 13,
                    "direction": 82.64,
                    "compassDirection": "W"
                },
                "primary": {
                    "height": 7,
                    "period": 13,
                    "direction": 72.94,
                    "compassDirection": "WSW"
                }
            }
        }

]
```

PHP to get the desired result

```
<?php
$url = 'http://magicseaweed.com/api/API_KEY/forecast/?spot_id=1';
$JSON = file_get_contents($url);



$data = json_decode($JSON,true);
    echo "[";


    foreach ($data as $record) {

    echo "[";
        echo "{$record['timestamp']}";
    echo ",";
        echo "{$record['swell']['absMinBreakingHeight']}";
    echo "]";
    echo ",";



    }   
echo "]";
?>
```

Returns: desired result minus last comma(edited for length)

```
[
    [
        1383609600,
        3.836
    ],
    [
        1383620400,
        4.081
    ],
]
```

what is the best way to proceed?

Comment: What's holding you back from `json_encode()`? It's always the right solution when the alternative is manually constructing a JSON string and hoping the format is correct.

Comment: It looks like what you need is a 2D array, but you're unsure how to construct it. Is that right?

Comment: I guess I just don't understand how to set it up in this case. am I on the right track with this?                                       $arr = ("a"=>"timestamp", "b"=>"swell.absMinBreakingHeight");
echo $json_encode($arr);

Comment: A good starting point would be valid JSON to do the decode on.  Try a tool like [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/).  Is as simple as converting to an array, iterating on it and doing the manipulation, then converting back to JSON with `json_encode`.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, with the correct PHP syntax.  `$arr = array()`; to initialize, then in your loop, append subarrays to it:  `$arr[] = array($record['timestamp'], $record['swell']['absMinBreakingHeight']);` after the loop `echo json_encode($arr);`

Comment: Ok, Michael, I got [[null,null]]

Comment: @user2883183 The answer by AbraCadaver fully fleshes out the idea in my comment, and should work for you.

Comment: Awesome!  I should be able to knock it out from here!  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of answering without a clear question, just build an array of what you want and encode it:

```
foreach ($data as $record) {
    $array[] = array($record['timestamp'], $record['swell']['absMinBreakingHeight']);
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data in a temporary array and use implode.

```
$data = json_decode($JSON,true);
$out = array();
foreach ($data as $record) {
    $out[] = "[{$record['timestamp']},{$record['swell']['absMinBreakingHeight']}]";
}   
echo "[" . implode(',', $out) . "]";
```

It would be better to use json_encode. Like this :

```
$data = json_decode($JSON,true);
$out = array();
foreach ($data as $record) {
    $out[] = array($record['timestamp'], $record['swell']['absMinBreakingHeight']);
}   
echo json_encode($out);
```

This code is even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In short.. removing the last char (comma here) as in your string can be done with:

```
$string = rtrim($string, ',');
```

Check for more detailed reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Answer (score 0):

```
**To remove the comma if there is no further array or object. Use the PHP chop function**. One can do like this example:-
    $jsonArrayString=[
      { "id":1, ---- , 'type':'open','draft':true},
      {"id":2, ---- , 'type':'open', 'draft':false},
      {"id":3, ---- , 'type':'closed', 'draft':false},
    ]
    $response = chop($jsonArrayString,",]");$response.=$string."]";
    $jsonArray = json_decode($response, true);
    
    Output:- [
      { "id":1, ---- , 'type':'open','draft':true},
      {"id":2, ---- , 'type':'open', 'draft':false},
      {"id":3, ---- , 'type':'closed', 'draft':false}
    ]
```